# Sheets doesn't exist on my googleapis object

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use the google sheets api. I've followed this tutorial

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

But every time i execute this line

```
    var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: Object #<GoogleApis> has no method 'sheets'
```

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?  I followed the guide pretty precisely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364031/what-does-uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method). You might encounter this error if you are trying to call a method of an object which does not exist. However, if the property does exist, but is not a function, you'll get an error like: `TypeError: Property 'bar' of object #<Object> is not a function`. It is simply the [default error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14364228/5832311) thrown when a property doesn't exist on an object.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was using an old enough verison of node that it the googleapi doesn't support sheets yet.

Updating my node version fixes the issue.